# Object in Component state shared with model file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React/Javascript app I have a component class as follow:

```
// CustomComponent.js

import * as model from "model.js";

class CustomComponent extends Component {

  state = {
    someObject: null
  };

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state.someObject = model.someObject;
  }

  ... // render, etc...

}
```

And I have a model file responsible for storing and computing stuff:

```
// model.js

export var someObject = {
  property1,
  property2,

  ...

  // Here are functions processing the data, for instance
  // someObject could be a matrix for a game, handling all the game logic

}

function changeObject() {
  // Somehow this function get called, from an animation loop or an external class for instance

  // This function changes properties of the object
}
```

Now, I would like the components (Custom, and its children) to update/render when the grid object is modified. Right now, the object in the state is changed, but components are not updated since `setState()` was not called.

How can I change my implementation for that? I want to keep having a separate file for handling model logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use state containers to do this. There are multiple such libraries:

1. `Redux` is possibly the most popular in the React community. It's a very clean application level state container / store - implementation of `Flux` and `Elm`. Here the state is immutable and you can change properties using actions and reducers and access them from the app state in any component.
2. `MobX` is another one that wraps your state into `observables`. Here the state is mutable and you have multiple stores (instead on app level single store in Redux)
3. Others: Some less popular ones are `RxJS` (observer pattern), `Alt` (Flux), `Relay` (Flux + GraphQL)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add redux e.c.t. You could use forceUpdate. 
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate

Comment: I'm not against adding Redux, I just didn't know it existed, I'm new to JS/React. Is that what Redux is made for?

Comment: Redux is mainly a state management tool, if youre dealing with state it can give you a but more control. https://redux.js.org